# Как исправить ошибку IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, list, список

Дан целочисленный массив размера N, не содержащий одинаковых чисел.
Проверить, образуют ли его элементы арифметическую прогрессию.
Если образуют, то вывести разность прогрессии, если нет — вывести 0.

```
n = int(input("Введите n: "))
print('Введите элементы массива: ')
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    arr.append(int(input()))
d = arr[2] - arr[1]
i = 2
flag = True
while flag and (i < n):
    if arr[i + 1] - arr[i] != d:
        flag = False
    i += 1
print(d if flag else 0)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/99CZQ9

```
n = int(input())
a = [int(input()) for x in range(n)]
d = a[1] - a[0]
print(d if str(a) == str([*range(a[0], a[0] + d*n, d)]) else 0)
```

Или, если делать нормально: https://ideone.com/hMi1Cs

```
n = int(input())
a = [int(input()) for x in range(n)]
d = a[1] - a[0]
print(d if all(x==y for x,y in zip(a, range(a[0], a[0] + d*n, d))) else 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> d = arr[2] - arr[1]
> ```

Индексация с 0 - ты посеял `arr[0]`, к тому же элементов может быть всего 2, тогда `arr[2]` не существует.

> ```
> while flag and (i < n):
>     if arr[i + 1] - arr[i] != d:
> ```

На последней итерации `i+1` выходит за границу - получается ровно `n`.